# Как сортировать ArrayList с объектами за двумя параметрами

Tags: java, коллекции

Есть класс `Employee` в котором есть `ArrayList<Employee>`, нужно отсортировать сотрудников в списке по `ЗП`, а если `ЗП` одинаковая за именем. Как отсортировать по `ЗП` я знаю, а вот как отсортировать при равной `ЗП` за именем не могу понять. Заранее спасибо. Можете дать хотя бы подсказку .

Comment: Что-то у Вас не то... Внутри `Employee` лежит переменная с типом `ArrayList`?

Comment: @kff public static ArrayList<Employee> = new ArrayList<Employee>,  да это лежит в классе Employee

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Предположим, имеем класс

```
class Employee {
    String name;
    double salary;
}
```

и переменную

```
ArrayList<Employee> employees;
```

Сортировать можно, например, следующим способом:

```
Collections.sort(
    employees,
    new Comparator<Employee>() {
        public int compare(final Employee e1, final Employee e2) {
            if (e1.salary < e2.salary)
                return -1;
            if (e2.salary > e2.salary)
                return 1;
            return e1.name.compareTo(e2.name);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: могли бы немного объяснить как работает Comparator

Comment: @AndreewAkulov Там нечего объяснять. Сравнивает он два элемента. Вначале по зряплате, а если зряплата одинаковая, то сравнит имена.

Comment: а почему  final Employee а не просто Employee ?

Comment: @AndreewAkulov Хороший тон программирования. `final` говорит, что мы не будем менять параметр внутри метода. Можно убрать, ничего не изменится.

Comment: @kff, поспорил бы на счет хорошего тона

Comment: @Russtam Мда... В `Java` `final` означает не то, что `const` в `C++`, поэтому я, пожалуй, соглашусь.

Comment: @Russtam И все же в Java рекомендуется финализировать переменные, если они не изменяют своего значения.

Comment: @pavlofff, ссылочку плиз где рекомендуется. 1. Ставить final не имеет смысла 2. Лишние ненужные final засоряют код и уменьшают читабельность.

Comment: final - тема для обсуждения в данном контексте. А если хотите рекомендаций, то прогоните код через checkstyle - он по умолчанию проверяет по Sun стандартам. Узнаете еще много интересного.