# Помощь новичку.Массивы

Tags: java

Подскажите как вывести: Вывести студента с лучшим баллом Вывести студента с наименьшим количеством пропусков Вывести студента-бюджетника; Вывести студентов на букву А Отсортировать студентов Студента женского пола Вот код :

```
public class FixedArrayStudents extends Students {
FixedArrayStudents() {
students = new ArrayList<>();

students.add(new Student("BBAWQE1", "BA-99", "yes", 499, 4.56, "menaaa1"));
students.add(new Student("BBAWQE2", "BA-991", "no", 4992, 4.55, "menaaa2"));
students.add(new Student("BBAWQE3", "BA-992", "yes", 4992, 4.45, "menaaa3"));
students.add(new Student("BBAWQE4", "BA-993", "no", 4993, 4.53, "menaaa4"));
students.add(new Student(("BBAWQE5", "BA-994", "yes", 4996, 42.5, "menaaa"));
students.add(new Student("BBAWQE6", "BA-99", "yes", 4997, 4.65, "menaaa5"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Обычно в коллекциях используют компаратор :

```
ObjectName[] arr = new ObjectName[10];
Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<ObjectName>() {
        public int compare(ObjectName o1, ObjectName o2) {
                return o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());
        }
});
```

Но вы будете сравнивать объекты по определенному полю.
Вот тут [Сортировка списка по полю элемента](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468248/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0) и тут [Как сортировать ArrayList с объектами за двумя параметрами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470568/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-arraylist-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) есть примеры.

Comment: мини пример где компаратор `return obj1.KolPropysk>obj2.KolPropysk`

Answer (score 0):

В классе должен присутствовать `get` и `set`. Используя [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), можем отсортировать:

```
Collections.sort(ArrayList<Object>, new Comparator<Class>() {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o1.getValue(), o2.getValue());
    }
});
```